# Why a SELECT inside a simultaneous transaction in MySQL is not returning the expect result?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, transactions

I'm running two simmultaneos PHP/MySQL scripts.
The gg MySQL table has 11 rows at the start of the scripts, with IDs ranging from 1 to 11.
I won't bother with the right functions, but will handle this as some sort of pseudocode.

In the first one, I have the following code:

```
php mysql_query "BEGIN WORK;"
php mysql_query "SELECT * FROM gg;"
php mysql_query "DELETE FROM gg WHERE id > 5;"
php "sleep(15)"
php mysql_query "SELECT * FROM gg;"
php mysql_query "COMMIT;"
```

The results of the first select are 11 rows.
The results of the second select are 05 rows.

In the second one, I have the following code (no sleep):

```
php mysql_query "BEGIN WORK;"
php mysql_query "SELECT * FROM gg;"
php mysql_query "DELETE FROM gg WHERE id > 5;"
php mysql_query "SELECT * FROM gg;"
php mysql_query "COMMIT;"
```

The results of the first select are 11 rows.
The results of the second select are 11 rows.

The sleep function is just used to force the delay before the commit.
The second select in the second transaction, is executed after the commit from the first script.

My doubt is: **Why the second SELECT in the second transaction is returning 11 rows if the commit from the first transaction was already performed?**

Comment: What database engine?

Comment: Check the innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit variable

Comment: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is set at default value: 0. And the enginne is InnoDB.